# Entering addresses in GoogleMaps "Directions" via VBA and retrieving miles

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

and many thanks in advance for any assistance!  i am needing to develop an automated excel (2010/13) frontend that will open IE, load in a 'starting point' and 'destination' address, then retrieve the 'miles'.   i have reviewed numerous links (eg, [VBA: not able to pull value within <input> tag using getelementsbyTagname().Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832431/vba-not-able-to-pull-value-within-input-tag-using-getelementsbytagname-valu)) and youtube videos (eg, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4C0zhbuo5lI) and think i have the basic vba code kernals correct; however, i simply cannot find the correct elementID (eg, "ie.document.getelementID("?????")...).   i have done numerous searches in the IE source html, as well as google chrome's 'inspect element' feature.  wonder if anyone could point me in the right direction here?

the url is: https://www.google.com/maps/dir///@34.2889944,-118.8442391,15z

and again, i'm trying to find the correct element for "Choose starting point" and "Choose destination", and then for the 'XXX miles'

i have also tried a couple of loops to determine '...elementByTagName()', without success.  for example:

```
...
Set AllHyperLinks = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("Directions")
    For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
       MsgBox hyper_link.innerText
        If hyper_link.innerText = "Choose starting point" Then
            hper_link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 ...
```

again, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 posts on how to play with Google API with VBA:

**Calculating distances between adresses:**

http://www.analystcave.com/excel-calculate-distances-between-addresses/

**Getting coordinates**

http://www.analystcave.com/excel-get-geolocation-coordinates-of-an-address/

Comment: thank you for your very quick repsonse!   as you mention in your instructions, i had to 'flip' the european decimal designator (,) with ".", and  simply convert to miles - all seems to be working fine, now - thnx again!

Comment: again, thnx - however, seems to fail at distances over 600mi (c. 1000km); is there a setting in the function code that can be 'expanded', or is this an intrinsic limitation with the the googlemaps api?

Comment: Please mark as answer then. Probably it fails over 1000km as I am guessing that the output would return the result with a comma like ",". I will look into my post to correct this soon

Comment: ANSWERED:  the 'distance in meters' function seems to work fine, AnalystCave - I flip the "," and ".", then convert to miles; all numbers are coming in fine, in "x,xxx.x" format.   thanks again!